# How to pass an arraylist from one servlet to another servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, arraylist

I have two Servlets, In first servlet I am creating an arraylist and paasing it to jsp page to display on UI, now I want to pass the same arraylist from the first servlet to another servlet. Below is the code forArraylist of first serlet. 
How to pass it to anather servlet in post method

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String startName=request.getParameter("startName");
    int noOfSenders=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("noOfSenders"));
    String domain =request.getParameter("domain");

    /*Code for List form function*/
    List<String> mails=new ArrayList<String>();

            for(int i=1;i<=noOfSenders;i++){
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
                sb.append(startName).append(i).append(domain); 
                mails.add(sb.toString());
            }
            System.out.println("response");
            response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(mails));
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setAttribute()`

```
request.setAttribute("mails", mails);
```

to retrieve :

```
ArrayList<String> list=(ArrayList<List>) request.getAttribute("mails");
```

Answer (score 0):

set it as session attribute you can access it anywhere inside application like below.

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("name",mails);
```

and you can access it in second servlet as

```
ArrayList<String> list=(ArrayList<List>)request.getSession().getAttribute("name");
```

Comment: `request.getSession().getAttribute("name");` returns an object. You need to type-cast it before using it.

Comment: Any good IDE will tell you to typecast while accessing, thought it's needless to mention

Comment: After geting name in servlet I want to pass it to for loop in the same doPost method-> for( senderInput : name ) bt here it is not working. giving error suggesting to make local variable of name..Please suggest

Comment: It(name) should be inside " " not as direct variable.

Comment: That would not be a perfect solution then. Even if OP doesn't use IDE, OP would get compilation error while compiling it. So then also OP can make changes but this is for the future reference if someone would have same doubt.

Comment: made changes accordingly @SanketMakani